# glibc detected double free or corruption

Tags: c++, crash, glibc

What is wrong with the code below.It runs Perfectly fine for some inputs and crashes for some special inputs?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;


struct event { 

string date,time,content;
bool is_high_priority;

};


int main() {

event one,two;
one.is_high_priority=false;
char tmp;

ofstream out_file("events" , ios::binary );


    cout<<"\nEnter Date(dd.mm) ";
    cin>>one.date;
    cout<<"\nEnter Time(hh:mm:ss) ";
    cin>>one.time;
    cout<<"\nenter content";
    cin>>one.content;

    if(tmp == 't') 
        one.is_high_priority = true;
    else
        one.is_high_priority = false;


    out_file.write((char*) &one, sizeof(one) );

    out_file.close();


    ifstream in_file("events" , ios::binary );
    in_file.read((char*)&two,sizeof(two));

    cout<<two.date<<" "<<two.time<<" "<<two.content<<" "<<two.is_high_priority;

    in_file.close();

}
```

It crashed for these inputs :
Enter Date(dd.mm) ankmjjdn md

Enter Time(hh:mm:ss) 
enter contentsnjs sjnsn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just save the bytes of a `std::string` object to a file and later load them again. The `std::string` contains pointers to dynamically allocated memory, and your save/load will just duplicate the pointer itself, not the pointed to data.

Comment: Well,The pointers are not deallocated right?So,why doesn't it work?Shouldn't it still give the output?

Comment: @nikel: They are deallocated when `one` and `two` go out of scope at the end of `main`. The destructors of the strings will be called, which will deallocate their dynamic memory.

Comment: Thats alright , but then What is the reason of crash?

Comment: @nikel: The stings in both "copies" of the struct contain pointers to the same dynamically allocated memory. When the first struct is destroyed it deallocates that memory. When the second struct is destroyed it tries to deallocate the same memory. This is where you get the error from glibc.

Comment: @sth : I tried running the program with different inputs.Seems like the crash is random, not dependent on the length of input string.Copying pointers and reconstructing is definitely a problem.But the crash does not happen for all inputs.How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(tmp == 't')
```

`tmp` is a local *uninitialized* variable,and you're using it as shown above.

So your code invokes undefined behavior. Nothing can be said further.

Comment: Even after removing that if else block, the problem still exists...So, i don't think its related to that.

Comment: @nikel: There are more problems in your code (as pointed out by other answer), but that doesn't mean that `tmp=='t'` is well-defined (given that `tmp` is an uninitialized variable).

Comment: Well,Okay..Actually I just stripped off this from a bigger code,forgot to strip this part off:-|.

Answer (score 0):

As @sth has pointed out, copying pointers to file and reinterpreting them, ends up in dup-free scenario.

However, I think there is something more subtle, please correct me if I am wrong. 
The program doesn't always crash on all inputs.  It is not even dependent on the lengths of the strings. I tried running the program with some test cases.

Note that the character 'space` is being treated as a delimeter. Even when you give your input, the characters after space are taken up by the next string.

So, the third string takes up the value till 'space'  The remaining input (till the carriage return) is still on the input buffer.

I am suspecting that when the second  object is constructed  from istream,the string after 'space' some overwrites a pointer, and this causes the corruption detection.